# Можно выбрать 2 элемента навигации слайдера за раз

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slick.js

Я использую slick slider для карусельки. На тач девайсах я могу выбрать сразу 2 элемента навигации по слайдеру (2 точки). Как это можно пофиксить ?
http://prntscr.com/m0ja4j

Пробовал такой вариант отсюда (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2651), но без успеха:

```
.slick-dots li button:focus:before {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button:focus:before {
    opacity: .75;
    color: #000;
}
```